# How to send multiple html form to different google sheet in the same file/database? I have a google sheet which have 3 sheets in total

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a **google sheet which have 3 sheets**, and I have **3 html** form in total. **Html don't run from google app script.**

Here's the code I have to send from html from to google sheet. But it only can send to one sheet, I would to send to another sheet. It's a javascript for google app script, it's a .cs file. The code is from here https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

```
// original gist: https://gist.github.com/willpatera/ee41ae374d3c9839c2d6 

function doGet(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
     var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
// shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
// this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
// [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
// we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

try {
 // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

 // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
 var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
 var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
 var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
 var row = []; 
 // loop through the header columns
 for (i in headers){
   if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
     row.push(new Date());
   } else { // else use header name to get data
     row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
   }
 }
 // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
 sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
 // return json success results
 return ContentService
       .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(e){
 // if error return this
 return ContentService
       .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} finally { //release lock
 lock.releaseLock();
}
}

function setup() {
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

I don't understand this part. I try to add in more variable and PropertiesService. And I can't get the result.

```
//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
     var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
```

```
try {
 // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
```

```
function setup() {
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: You must have some way to differentiate the 3 types of forms being submitted to your webapp. So, use the event object to determine which sheet you need to append the data to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4JMjmwHPEg

I have made a tutorial on youtube you can check the link in the description of youtube for source code.

You have to create duplicate functions for every sheets you have in spreadsheet. Check below code which you need to add in spreadsheet .gs file. for further information you can check the youtube link provided.

```js
// See front-end example at: http://codepen.io/notarazi/pen/yMqyXX
// Usage
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
    //var SHEET_NAME;   
     
//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
 return handleResponse(e);
}
function doPost(e){
 return handleResponse(e);
}
function handleResponse(e) {
 // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
 // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
 // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
 // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
 var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
 lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

    //Sheet1
     try {
       var action = e.parameter.action;

       if (action == 'create') {
         return create(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'retrieve') {
         return retrieve(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'update') {
         return update(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'delete') {
         return del(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'findRowId'){
         return findRowId(e.parameter.findstr);
       }
     } catch(e){
       // if error return this
       return ContentService
             .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
             .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
     } finally { //release lock
       lock.releaseLock();
     }


    //Sheet2
    try {
       var action = e.parameter.action;

       if (action == 'create_1') {
         return create_1(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'retrieve_1') {
         return retrieve_1(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'update_1') {
         return update_1(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'delete_1') {
         return del_1(e);
       } 
       else if (action == 'findRowId'){
         return findRowId(e.parameter.findstr);
       }    
     } catch(e){
       // if error return this
       return ContentService
             .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
             .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
     } finally { //release lock
       lock.releaseLock();
     }     
    
}
function getDataArr(headers, e){
   var row = [];

   // loop through the header columns
   for (i in headers){
     var d= new Date();
     if (headers[i] == "tid"){ // special case if you include a unix Timestamp column
       row.push(d.getTime());
     }else if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
       row.push(new Date());
     } else { // else use header name to get data
       row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
     }
   }
 
   return row;
}
function create0(e){
   // return json success results
   return ContentService
         .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": 99}))
         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
function findRowId(data) {
 var SHEET_NAME = "Published Online"; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 //var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);  // like A:A
 var column = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);  
 var values = column.getValues();

 var data1=Number(data);
 var row = 0;
 var result = 0;
 while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== data ) {
   row++;
 }

 if (values[row][0] === data)
   result= row+1;
 else
   result = -1;
 
//result += data1;
 return ContentService
   .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "values": result}))
   .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
function findInColumn(data) {
 var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 //var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);  // like A:A
 var column = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);  
 var values = column.getValues();

 //data=1490461629269;
 var testdata = Number(data);
 var row = 0;

 while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== testdata ) {
   row++;
 }


 if (values[row][0] === testdata)
   return row+1;
 else
   return -1;
 

//  return ContentService
//    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "values": row}))
//    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
function findInColumn_s2(data) {
 var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet2"; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 //var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);  // like A:A
 var column = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);  
 var values = column.getValues();

 //data=1490461629269;
 var testdata = Number(data);
 var row = 0;

 while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== testdata ) {
   row++;
 }

 if (values[row][0] === testdata)
   return row+1;
 else
   return -1;
 

//  return ContentService
//    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "values": row}))
//    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}

function findInRow(data) {
 var SHEET_NAME = "Published Online"; 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var rows  = sheet.getDataRange.getValues();

 for (var r=0; r<rows.length; r++) {
   if ( rows[r].join("#").indexOf(data) !== -1 ) {
     return r+1;
   }
 }

 return -1;
 
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
//SHEET 1 CREATE
function create(e) {
   var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet1';
   // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 
   // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
   var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
   var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
   var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
   var row = getDataArr(headers, e);
   // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
   // return json success results
   return ContentService
         .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 1 RETRIEVE
function retrieve(e) {
 var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet1'; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
 var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var range =  sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns);
 var values = range.getValues();
 
 return ContentService
   .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "values": values}))
   .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 1 UPDATE
function update(e) {
    var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet1';
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

    var rowId = findInColumn(e.parameter.tid);



    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
    var row = getDataArr(headers, e);
    //var rowId = e.parameter.rowId;
    var tid= row[0];

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(rowId, 1, 1, numColumns).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "tid": tid}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 1 DELETE
function del(e) {
 var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet1'; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 var rowId = findInColumn(e.parameter.tid);

  
 sheet.deleteRow(rowId);
 // return json success results
 return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "rowId": rowId}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);   
  
  
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
//SHEET 2 CREATE
function create_1(e) {
   var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet2';
   // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 
   // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
   var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
   var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
   var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
   var row = getDataArr(headers, e);
   // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
   // return json success results
   return ContentService
         .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 2 RETRIEVE
function retrieve_1(e) {
 var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet2'; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
 var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var range =  sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns);
 var values = range.getValues();
 
 return ContentService
   .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "values": values}))
   .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 2 UPDATE
function update_1(e) {
    var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet2';
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

    var rowId = findInColumn_s2(e.parameter.tid);



    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
    var row = getDataArr(headers, e);
    //var rowId = e.parameter.rowId;
    var tid= row[0];

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(rowId, 1, 1, numColumns).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "tid": tid}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
//SHEET 2 DELETE
function del_1(e) {
 var SHEET_NAME = e.parameter.sheet_name || 'Sheet2'; 
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
 var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 var rowId = findInColumn_s2(e.parameter.tid);

 sheet.deleteRow(rowId);
 // return json success results
 return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "rowId": rowId}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);   

}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/


//SETUP
function setup() {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the sheet that you exactly want, you can set another parameter in the [Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)  `e.parameters`.  In each of your forms add a key/value pair defining the name of where you want the form to be submitted. For example:

#### For the first sheet

```
sheetName=Sheet1
```

#### For the second sheet

```
sheetName=Sheet2
```

If you are using a ***Get Request*** the URL would look like this:

`https://script.google.com/a/your-domain/macros/s/your-id/exec?sheetName=Sheet1`.

Then, you would only need to pass that value to the [***.getSheetByName()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) like this:

`var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameters.sheetName);`